# What is a "Unix-like" compiler?

Tags: c++, unix, compiler-construction, wikipedia

On the Wikipedia [List Of Compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers) page, it tells you if a compiler is "Unix-like". What does this mean? Does it effect how to write the source code? I'm coming over from MinGW (which is listed as "Unix-like" to another compiler, just wanted to see if this was a important thing to look out for).

Answer (score 4):

I think you miss-understand. That column indicates **if your compiler is available** on a "unix-like" OS/platform, of which linux is an example.

You can see this by the fact that MingGW is listed under the windows column for compilers (GCC) which are available on many platforms, which means that MinGW is the windows port/version of GCC (in the context of this question).